# AWS Amplify deploy Angular 9. Cannot find module

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am trying to set up deployment for my angular 9 project using AWS Amplify. This is my .YML file

```
version: 0.1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - nvm use $VERSION_NODE_12
        - npm install
        - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
      commands:
        - nvm use $VERSION_NODE_12
        - ng build app-call --prod
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist/apps/app-call
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

But I am getting a build error:

```
2020-04-08T13:57:57.706Z [WARNING]: ERROR in libs/call/src/classes/index.ts:1:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './Util'.
                                    1 import Util from './Util';
```

Locally the solution builds fine. Looks like I am missing something. Any idea what?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem where the project runs locally but not when published to amplify, it turned out that files need to be named like this **name.domain.ts**.

so yours will be **util.model.ts** or **util.service.ts** and like so.

There should be a config somewhere in **tsconfig** to allow naming style you are using but I think it is a good practice to follow the standards.